# Downgrade CoffeeScript Version

Tags: macos, coffeescript

Recently, due to a problem, I had reinstall all my libraries which included CoffeeScript also. My problem is that my team has one version of CoffeeScript while I have a newer one. So every time we push code there is conflict in javascript. Any pointers on how I can downgrade CoffeeScript version in MAC OS would be really helpful.
Operation System: OS X El Capitan installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used NPM, install the older version of CoffeeScript with the following command:

```
 npm install -g coffee-script@1.11.1
```

Close and reopen your terminal.

Check if you have the correct version installed:

```
coffee -v
```

On a side note, it might be better to maintain your project dependencies with `package.json`. That way, your team will *always* be in sync with the relevant package versions.

```
{
  "name": "coffee-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.coffee",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/coffee index.coffee"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "coffee-script": "^1.11.1"
  }
}
```

Just run `npm install` to install project dependencies.

And run `npm start` to start app with the correct "coffee version" for your app.

Comment: Thanks @Jon. This helped.

Comment: Hi After doing this the CoffeeScript is not compiling. Did i miss something?

Comment: I got it. I had missed the part where you need to completely shut down the terminal and start again.